# mount fat16 raw file on windows using c# or powershell

Tags: c#, windows, powershell, mount

I have a fat 16 image that I would like to have mounted and copy some files in to, then unmount the drive

I have to do this in powershell or c#, can any one help me providing references to the way to do this.

Comment: How come you have to only use Powershell / C#? Why not more suitable tools?

Comment: hey i have to do this as part of another application that I am running... you can suggest any free tools that I can use to do this. please do suggest any method/ API from msdn that can help me to do this.